# How do I Dispose() of an image in a picture box?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have code that looks like this:

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(...); //doesn't matter how this image is constructed
pictureBox1.Image = b;
//b.Dispose() placed here crashes the application and so does "using" if used on the declaration of 'b'
```

Since in C# you should dispose of everything that is `IDisposable`, this image needs to be disposed of at some point. It seems that the property `PictureBox.Image` only makes a shallow copy, so I need to keep the object alive (aka not `Dispose()` of it) for the entire time the image stays in the box. If I later change the image in the box:

```
pictureBox1.Image = b2;
```

Does the property dispose of it for me? Or should I do it manually:

```
Image im = pictureBox1.Image;
pictureBox1.Image = b2;
im.Dispose();
```

Comment: "It seems that the property PictureBox.Image only makes a shallow copy," What makes you think this?

Comment: If the disposable pattern is implemented correctly, nobody needs to dispose it. The Image itself will do in co-work with the garbage collector.

Comment: @DStanley because if it was a deep copy, when I disposed of `b` the app wouldn't crash (look at that commented line)

Comment: @DarkAtom It's actually  a _reference assignment_, which I suppose is a _very_ shallow copy in some respects.

Comment: @DStanley Okok it's just terminology stuff I get it :)) I always thought that assigning 2 references is called a shallow copy, because the 2 will refer to the same object.

Comment: @DarkAtom The more common meaning of "shallow copy" is to copy all of the values of first-level properties, but not make copies of any reference types.

Comment: The Image assigned to a PictureBox is not disposed of automatically when you assign another. It's not really hard to check this out, simply changing images in a loop with the Diagnostic Tools panel open. You can see the memory usage grow, you can also see the Garbage Collector *interventions*, but the unmanaged resources won't be released. You can simply do: `pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose(); pictureBox1.Image = [another object]`. Do this in a loop, you'll see that the memory consumption, handles and GDI objects, never grow.

Answer (score 1):

Yes...if you change the `.Image` property, your previous image will EVENTUALLY be disposed of automatically.

If you are absolutely sure that you no longer need the previous image, you can assign it to a temporary variable, assign a new image to your picturebox, then dispose of the temp variable:

```
Image tmp = pictureBox1.Image;
pictureBox1.Image = b2;
tmp.Dispose();
```

Comment: I doubt that this has to do with the `.Image` property.